# PCA using MDAanalysis (python3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pca, mdanalysis

I started to work in the field of computational chemistry and I was ask to do Principal Component Analysis on some trajectory from molecular dynamics. I was told to use MDAnalysis package, thus I find one tutorial on their page a tried to follow it (but I included my own inputs of course) to see if it will be working. I have never done analysis like this ad I am also new to python coding.
I attached my code inspired by tutorial. But it doesnt work for me, it raises many errors, one of the errors is that it cant take my inputs (topology is PDB file, coordinate is XTC file), but those are formats which are listed in supported formats or other error is that "class PCA" is not defined.
I didnt find much about dealing with PCA using MDAanalysis from other people, thus I hoped that here I could find someone, who have ever done something like this and could, please, help me. I have alreadz tried related subreddits, but without result.

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import
import MDAnalysis as mda
import MDAnalysis.analysis.pca as pca

from six.moves import range
import warnings

import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate

from MDAnalysis import Universe
from MDAnalysis.analysis.align import _fit_to
from MDAnalysis.lib.log import ProgressMeter


u = mda.Universe("L22trial.pdb", "L22trial.xtc") 


PCA = mda.analysis.pca.PCA
class PCA():
    pca = PCA(u, select='backbone').run()
    pca_space =  pca.transform(u.select_atoms('backbone'))

    def __init__(self, universe, select='all', align=False, mean=None,
                 n_components=None, **kwargs):
            super(PCA, self).__init__(universe.trajectory, **kwargs)
            self._u = universe

            self.align = align
            self._calculated = False
            self.n_components = n_components
            self._select = select
            self._mean = mean

    def _prepare(self):
        self._u.trajectory[self.start]
        self._reference = self._u.select_atoms(self._select)
        self._atoms = self._u.select_atoms(self._select)
        self._n_atoms = self._atoms.n_atoms

        if self._mean is None:
            self.mean = np.zeros(self._n_atoms*3)
            self._calc_mean = True
        else:
            self.mean = self._mean.positions
            self._calc_mean = False

        if self.n_frames == 1:
            raise ValueError('No covariance information can be gathered from a single trajectory  frame.\n')

        n_dim = self._n_atoms * 3
        self.cov = np.zeros((n_dim, n_dim))
        self._ref_atom_positions = self._reference.positions
        self._ref_cog = self._reference.center_of_geometry()
        self._ref_atom_positions -= self._ref_cog

        if self._calc_mean:
            interval = int(self.n_frames // 100)
            interval = interval if interval > 0 else 1
            format = ("Mean Calculation Step %(step)5d/%(numsteps)d [%(percentage)5.1f%%]")
            mean_pm = ProgressMeter(self.n_frames if self.n_frames else 1, interval=interval, verbose=self._verbose, format=format)
            for i, ts in enumerate(self._u.trajectory[self.start:self.stop:self.step]):
                if self.align:
                    mobile_cog = self._atoms.center_of_geometry()
                    mobile_atoms, old_rmsd = _fit_to(self._atoms.positions, self._ref_atom_positions, self._atoms, mobile_com=mobile_cog, ref_com=self._ref_cog)
                else:
                    self.mean += self._atoms.positions.ravel()
                mean_pm.echo(i)
            self.mean /= self.n_frames

        self.mean_atoms = self._atoms
        self.mean_atoms.positions = self._atoms.positions

    def _single_frame(self):
        if self.align:
            mobile_cog = self._atoms.center_of_geometry()
            mobile_atoms, old_rmsd = _fit_to(self._atoms.positions, self._ref_atom_positions, self._atoms, mobile_com=mobile_cog, ref_com=self._ref_cog)
            x = mobile_atoms.positions.ravel()
        else:
            x = self._atoms.positions.ravel()
        x -= self.mean
        self.cov += np.dot(x[:, np.newaxis], x[:, np.newaxis].T)

    def _conclude(self):
        self.cov /= self.n_frames - 1
        e_vals, e_vects = np.linalg.eig(self.cov)
        sort_idx = np.argsort(e_vals)[::-1]
        self.variance = e_vals[sort_idx]
        self.variance = self.variance[:self.n_components]
        self.p_components = e_vects[:self.n_components, sort_idx]
        self.cumulated_variance = (np.cumsum(self.variance) / np.sum(self.variance))

        self._calculated = True

    def transform(self, atomgroup, n_components=None, start=None, stop=None, step=None):
        if not self._calculated:
            raise ValueError('Call run() on the PCA before using transform')
        if isinstance(atomgroup, Universe):
            atomgroup = atomgroup.atoms
        if(self._n_atoms != atomgroup.n_atoms):
            raise ValueError('PCA has been fit for {} atoms. Your atomgroup has {} atoms'.format(self._n_atoms, atomgroup.n_atoms))
        if not (self._atoms.types == atomgroup.types).all():
            warnings.warn('Atom types do not match with types used to fit PCA')

        traj = atomgroup.universe.trajectory
        start, stop, step = traj.check_slice_indices(start, stop, step)
        n_frames = len(range(start, stop, step))

        dim = (n_components if n_components is not None else self.p_components.shape[1])
        dot = np.zeros((n_frames, dim))

        for i, ts in enumerate(traj[start:stop:step]):
            xyz = atomgroup.positions.ravel() - self.mean
            dot[i] = np.dot(xyz, self.p_components[:, :n_components])

        return dot

def cosine_content(pca_space, i):
    t = np.arange(len(pca_space))
    T = len(pca_space)
    cos = np.cos(np.pi * t * (i + 1) / T)
    return ((2.0 / T) * (scipy.integrate.simps(cos*pca_space[:, i])) ** 2 /
            scipy.integrate.simps(pca_space[:, i] ** 2))
```

Comment: can you provide the error stack message. that could help.

Comment: ValueError: '' isn't a valid topology format, nor a coordinate format
   from which a topology can be minimally inferred.
   You can use 'Universe(topology, ..., topology_format=FORMAT)'
   to explicitly specify the format and
   override automatic detection. Known FORMATs are:
   dict_keys(['PSF', 'TOP', 'PRMTOP', 'PARM7', 'PDB', 'ENT', 'XPDB', 'PQR', 'GRO', 'CRD', 'PDBQT', 'DMS', 'TPR', 'MOL2', 'DATA', 'LAMMPSDUMP', 'XYZ', 'TXYZ', 'ARC', 'GMS', 'CONFIG', 'HISTORY', 'XML', 'MMTF', 'GSD', 'MINIMAL'])

Comment: Can you explain why you import PCA from  mda.analysis.pca.PCA and afterward you define a class named PCA. What you seem to be willing to do is derived a class from PCA in  that case rewrite **class PCA** has following **class MyPCA(PCA)** . Can you give a link from where you the  example that inspired you from this piece of code.

Comment: This is the link: https://www.mdanalysis.org/docs/_modules/MDAnalysis/analysis/pca.html

Comment: I am not sure, should I delete  `PCA = mda.analysis.pca.PCA` ? When I use only "class PCA" in the script, it raises error that class PCA is not defined. In the original script they use, in addition, `class PCA(AnalysisBase)` . They imported AnalysisBase from module ".base", but it was my first error, that there is no module like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you copied and pasted the PCA class itsefl. My guess is that you don't need to do this (I have never used that module so it s just a guess).
The documentation ( https://www.mdanalysis.org/docs/documentation_pages/analysis/pca.html ) seems to indicate the only thing you need to do is the following

```
    import MDAnalysis as mda
    import MDAnalysis.analysis.pca as pca

    u = mda.Universe("L22trial.pdb", "L22trial.xtc") 

    mypca = pca.PCA(u, select='backbone').run()
    pca_space =  mypca.transform(u.select_atoms('backbone'))
```

If you have an error message "No module named 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca.PCA'; 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca' is not a package" it means what it says :-).
That means there is no package on your computer named MDAnalysis. to fix this you need to install using **pip install** command or **conda** if you use conda package manager. See this link https://www.mdanalysis.org/pages/installation_quick_start/

Looking at the link https://www.mdanalysis.org/docs/_modules/MDAnalysis/analysis/pca.html from which you got inspired it confirmed my first guess and I think my answer should allow you using that package.

Comment: But this raises me error : No module named 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca.PCA'; 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca' is not a package

Comment: the link https://www.mdanalysis.org/docs/_modules/MDAnalysis/analysis/pca.html first describes how to used PCA class then describes PCA class design. Just try what I said, the simple piece of code in my answer, after installing the MDAanalysis package and see what you get. If you use windows it is recommended to install with conda (see https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/wiki/MDAnalysis-on-Windows)

Comment: I use Linux and there is installed MDAnalysis package (I checked it once again). Still, unfortunately, raises error: No module named 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca.PCA'; 'MDAnalysis.analysis.pca' is not a package

Comment: try the code I have just modified : **import MDAnalysis.analysis.pca as pca** instead of import **MDAnalysis.analysis.pca.PCA as PCA**. Also I renamed the variable **pca** as **mypca** and changed the call on **run()**

Comment: Thanks! Now it doesnt return any error. Do you work with mda package?

Comment: no I don't, I have never used, but PCA is a subject of interest for me. BR

Comment: Most of the support for MDAnalysis happens on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/mdnalysis-discussion

There are also a few resources to get started with the library, see https://www.mdanalysis.org/pages/learning_MDAnalysis/

Specifically, for PCA there‘s an example notebook https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/MDAnalysis/binder-notebook/blob/master/notebooks/analysis/PCA_Tutorial.ipynb —we‘re happy to help if there are questions.